# Angular routing inside a http post Observable / subscribe

Tags: angular, angular-router, angular10, angular-observable

I am trying to direct a user to a dashboard inside a `response` of a `httpClient.post` request. The page navigates "well" (it shows on the url bar) but most elements of the components DOM do not load.

This is the post in the service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { retry, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

const baseUrl = 'https://my-api.com';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  postSomeData(data): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpClient.post(baseUrl + '/postSomeData', data)
  }
```

And this is how I use it in a component:

```
this.apiService.postSomeData(params)
            .subscribe(
              async response => {
                response = await response;
                if(response.response == 'success'){
                  // success logic

                }else{
                  // failure message
                }
              },
              error => {
                // error logic
              },
              () => {
                // window.top.location.href = "https://" + window.location.host;
                this.router.navigate(["/dashboard"]);
              });
```

When the `subscribe` is complete and the router navigates to the dashboard, this is the incomplete load of the dashboard DOM that I get:
[image]

If I put the navigation (`this.router.navigate(["/dashboard"]);`) anywhere outside the subscribe or I reload the page manually or programatically (`window.top.location.href = "https://" + window.location.host;`) the page (DOM) loads just fine:
[image]

So how can I implement the navigation inside within the subscribe and have a complete DOM load of the dashboard component? Clearly the `complete` function within the subscribe isn't working for me. The commented out full page reload (`window.top.location.href = "https://" + window.location.host;`) within the complete function works but it isn't the angular way.

Answer (score 3):

The first response returned from a `subscribe` is executed when the HTTP method was successful, so there's no need to check for a response.

The second response is executed when an error.

So in fact you could simplify your code by a lot by just doing the following:

```
this.apiService.postSomeData(params)
            .subscribe(
              () => {
                // success logic, HTTP statuscode 20X
              },
              () => {
                // error logic, when a HTTP error has been thrown
              },
              () => {
                // executed when the HTTP function has been completed, doesn't matter whether success or error
                this.router.navigate(["/dashboard"]);
              });
```

I think the problem had to do with the `async` and the `if`-clause. There's no reason to use an `async` and `if`-clause there. This ought to fix it.

You can always use `debugger` in your code to see when a function is executed. If you don't fully get when which part of the `subscribe` is executed, I recommend doing this a few times.